# Assigning images to 2D arrays in another Class

Tags: java, arrays, image, class, multidimensional-array

I have a Square class, and a NormalMode Class. I have created a 2D array of Square in the NormalMode Class like so:

```
Square[][] square = new Square[4][4];
```

Then Initialized it like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < square.length; j++){
          square[i][j] = new Square();
       }
}
```

Now, how would i assign images to each of those objects in the 2D array? Would i somehow assign it in the Square class file? Or would i do it in the NormalMode class? I'm still very new to programming, I would appreciate some explanation in your answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "assign images"? What is the `Square` class, and where do images come into it? We don't know what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: `square[i][j].setImage("somePreloadImage")` ??

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to make a simple memory game. The game will consist of 16 squares in a 4x4 grid. So i decided to make 2 images for it, an image for when the square is a correct one, and another for when it's incorrect. I then proceeded to making this array in the Normal Mode class, and realized "How am i going to handle these images?". I was dumbfounded for hours, and decided to just ask on here. Basically what i wan't to do is make 16 squares that have a certain image depending if the Square is a correct square or incorrect. I believe this goes in the Square class, but i'm unsure.

Comment: @MrPork: Well what do you want your `Square` class to contain? Does it have any information in it apart from which image to show? If not, you may not need the class at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet It holds boolean information, and a createRandom method that i call when normal mode starts. That method creates an int that either holds the value 0 or 1, which in turn sets the squares corresponding boolean values. The Square can be correct or incorrect.

Comment: It sounds like the `Square` should just have a `boolean` value then, rather than an `Image` field... but you can use just two `Image` objects and use whichever one is appropriate based on the `boolean`. Think about whether you want the `Square` class to be aware of the UI, or whether you want it to be more just logic. Also think about whether you really need the `Square` class at all, or whether you could just have a `boolean[][]` variable in `NormalMode` (if `Square` really just holds a `boolean` field).